# Compress JavaScript with gzip

Tags: javascript, optimization, compression, gzip

I ran Google PageSpeed Insights to optimize my site and it recommended archiving the numerous JavaScript files with gzip.

How does this work? How are the files imported/included as an archive? Can they all be inside one big archive, or should they be individual archives?

Comment: You need to specify what language are you using on the server, and also what server are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your web server to do the compression for you; in the case of [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#addoutputfilterbytype):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: So I add these lines to the .htaccess and then upload a single archive with all my JavaScript files inside?

Comment: @Bobe if you want to combine all your JS into one file, go ahead. It doesn't have to be an archive, you can leave it as a single .js file

Comment: You don't need to upload anything different, just change the web server configuration.

Comment: Ok, I understand that after reading through the link provided by PherricOxide and HackedByChinese. However, it says I can use mod_deflate or mod_gzip, how do I select the latter?

Comment: @Bobe that depends on your version of Apache, it's called `mod_deflate` now (version >= 2)

Comment: I ran Insights again with the modified .htaccess and the overall score went from 70 to 59. In fact, it's added minified JavaScript files and CSS files to the list of uncompressed files.

Comment: @Bobe well, you obviously have to test the configuration by downloading a file with your browser and check the network request / response to see if gzip'ed data was sent.

Comment: Yeah I tested it at http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php and it says there's no compression. The server is running Apache 2.2.22, why wouldn't the .htaccess work?

Comment: @Bobe for this to work in `.htaccess` your server needs to have the proper `AllowOverride` setting, in this case that would be `FileInfo`.

Comment: @Jack How would I go about enabling that?

Comment: @Bobe you have to check and edit the main Apache configuration file; if this is not possible, you have to ask the one who can; and don't forget to restart the server after making any changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think they were referring to having static content compressed by the web server. The files themselves are the same, but you may need to do some configuration with whatever web server you have.

See [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Most web servers (Apache, IIS, Node) support this feature internally or with plugins. You usually just have to enable it on the web server, you don't actually create the zip files or change anything manually. Take a look at http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/